# Retrieve first two digits from google v3 API response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, formatting

I'm getting "sick" with in a simply problem. I'm using OpenLayers to display a map with a google map base layer. As an user suggestion i'm doing a request to the google geocode API with an address provided by the user.

The problem:

The google api response is like that:

```
lat: "-34.8836111"
lon: "-56.1819444"
```

After that i have to create a LonLat OpenLayers object and make a transformation, like that:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.longitude,
                                    position.coords.latitude)
                      .transform(
                                  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), //transform from WGS 1984
                                              window.user_map.getProjectionObject() //to Spherical Mercator Projection
                                            );
```

The problem is that lonLat format is in a different precission.

```
lat: -4148075.5841099103
lon: -6254145.441513423
```

I need to have only the first two integers digits that allow that displayable using the google map API (in another page).

Any help? This could be solved in ruby for example in a bebore_save method that formats the coordinates, or in the client side with javascript/jquery

Regards.

Comment: The problem is that you are not allowed to do this: [The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits) . `OpenLayers.Layer.Google`  is not a Google map. OpenLayers has a written consent to use data from google, but I'm afraid you don't.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. How to get only the first two integer digits from the lonLat Openlayers struct?

Comment: @Dr.Molle i retrieve the data of a place from the google API, then i place that in an OpenLayers map with any problems. After that i need to get the openlayers map data and put it in a google map. Sounds streaky but is that i have to do. haha.

Comment: *i retrieve the data of a place from the google API, then i place that in an OpenLayers map* ...that's what I said, you are not allowed to do this.

Comment: I think that OpenLayers (GIS display) it's only a container for the base_layer (that comes from Google). Anyway, the question is in another way. I will send an email to google support just in case.

Comment: @carter, got the question now?

Comment: Are you really just looking for the number divided by 10000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with a inverse order transformation before showing the second google map.

Like that:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.longitude,
                                position.coords.latitude)
                  .transform(
                             window.user_map.getProjectionObject(), //transform from WGS 1984
                                          new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326") //to Spherical Mercator Projection
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert numbers to a string:

```
var myStringLat = 123456.123654 + "";
```

Then get first two digits:

```
var myStringLat2Digits = myStringLat.substr(1, 2);
```

Then convert back to numbers:

```
var myNumberLat2Digits = Number(myStringlat2Digits, 10);
```

Comment: With this i lose the decimal digits...! But could be an idea.

Comment: Then get the decimals and concat them to the first two digits using same method.